# how to encrypt password with hash sha512 in codeigniter while uploading to db

Tags: php, codeigniter, web, hash, passwords

I want to encrypt my password using hashing when submitting data to the database kindly guide me to where to change the code

Can anyone help me out to find the best encryption method for Codeigniter?

```
public function register(){ 
    if($this->isUserLoggedIn){ 
          redirect('users/account'); 
         } 
    $data = array(); 
    if($this->session->userdata('success_msg')){ 
        $data['success_msg'] = $this->session->userdata('success_msg'); 
        $this->session->unset_userdata('success_msg'); 
    } 
    if($this->session->userdata('error_msg')){ 
        $data['error_msg'] = $this->session->userdata('error_msg'); 
        $this->session->unset_userdata('error_msg'); 
    } 
    if($this->input->post('signupSubmit')){ 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'First Name', 'trim|required'); 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('last_name', 'Last Name', 'trim|required'); 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobile_no', 'Mobile', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[10]|regex_match[/^[0-9]{10}$/]|callback_mobile_no_check'); 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email'); 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required'); 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('conf_password', 'confirm password', 
'required|matches[password]'); 
 $userData = array( 
            'first_name' => strip_tags($this->input->post('first_name')), 
            'last_name' => strip_tags($this->input->post('last_name')), 
            'email' => strip_tags($this->input->post('email')), 
            'password' => strip_tags($this->input->post('password')), 
            'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'), 
            'mobile_no' => strip_tags($this->input->post('mobile_no')) 
        ); 
            if($this->form_validation->run() == true){ 
            $insert = $this->users_model->insert($userData); 
            if($insert){ 
                $this->session->set_userdata('success_msg', 'Your account registration has been successful. Please login to your account.'); 
                redirect('users/login'); 
            }else{ 
                $data['error_msg'] = 'Some problems occured, please try again.'; 
            } 
        }else{ 
            $data['error_msg'] = 'Please fill all the mandatory fields.'; 
        } 
    }
    // Load view 
    $data['pvalue'] = array('view'=>'login_view','pgTitle'=>'Log In');
    $this->loadView($data);
    
    
}
```

Comment: Just to remove any confusion: encryption and hashing are two very different things. Encryption can be decrypted (get the original value back) while hashing is one way (you can't "dehash" a hash). You don't encrypt passwords, you hash them. You can always use PHP's built in [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to get a secure hash and then verify the password against a hash using [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). Those are core functions in PHP and are the recommended way of handling password hashes.

Comment: You should also not use `strip_tags()` around the password since that can completely change the password, even make it blank. If someone has a password like `<foo bar password>`, then `strip_tags()` will return an empty string (which is not a very secure password). Just leave the password as is without any modifications.

Comment: You should also validate the other fields after you've sanitized them (like removing tags). If someone would write `<hello world>` as first/last name, your validation would accept it but they would still be blank in your database (for the same reason the password would be blank)